# Pyramid fill - how to write input 2 and output [1,1][1,1]

Tags: python

Read an integer nn from standard input and fill the square  n×n with integers as follows:

```
1 2 3 2 1
2 3 4 3 2
3 4 5 4 3
2 3 4 3 2
1 2 3 2 1
```

or

```
1 2 2 1
2 3 3 2
2 3 3 2
1 2 2 1
```

That is, numbers in each column / row increase by one when moving along the column/row towards the center of the matrix.

Implement the matrix as a list of lists of integers, and print the resulting list of lists on standard output.

there is my code, but it cant be output [1,1][1,1],it will be output []

MY CODE:

```
N = int(input("Enter N value:"))

k = (N) - 1

matrix = [[0 for i in range(k)] for j in range(k)]
for i in range (k):
    matrix = []
    for j in range (k):
        print(matrix)
```

Comment: `matrix` is always `[]` in your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided does nothing, I'm assuming that's a copy error on your part.

Anyways, the following should work but bear in mind, that the reversals are not creating deep copies in the following code so if you try to edit the matrix once it is built, it may not behave the way you expect it to.

```
import math

N = int(input("Enter N value:"))
matrix = []

# iterate over the first math.ceil(N/2) rows
for i in range(math.ceil(N/2)):
    matrix.append([])
    
    # create the core numbers
    # if i = 0, N = 4, range would be 1,2
    # if i = 1, N = 5, range would be 2,3,4
    for j in range(i+1, i+1+math.ceil(N/2)):
        matrix[i].append(j)
    
    # create copy and reverse it excluding the center element of row
    matrix[i] += matrix[i][0:N//2][::-1]

# reverse and append the existing matrix excluding the center row
matrix += matrix[0:N//2][::-1]
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never populate `matrix` you are only looping and reassigning `matrix`to an empty list.

You can use a list comprehension to get the first half, then append it's reverse. You will need some logic to determine what to do if it is even or odd but that's mainly trivial:

```
n = int(input("Enter N value: "))
half = n // 2
is_odd = n % 2

matrix = [[*range(1 + i, half + i + is_odd+1),
           *range(half + i, i, -1)] for i in range(half+is_odd)]
matrix += matrix[:-is_odd or None][::-1]
```

Result: *(formatted as your expected output)*

```
>>> Enter N value: 4
[[1, 2, 2, 1],
 [2, 3, 3, 2],
 [2, 3, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 1]]
```

---

```
>>> Enter N value: 5
[[1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
 [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
 [3, 4, 5, 4, 3],
 [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the intersection of values from an increasing, then decreasing list:

```
n = 4
R = [(n-abs(i))//2 for i in range(1-n,n,2)]  # [0, 1, 1, 0]
M = [ [r+c+1 for c in R] for r in R]
print(*M,sep="\n")

[1, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Visually (looking at R)

```
r+c+1 for n=4       r+c+1 for n=5

R | 0 1 1 0         R | 0 1 2 1 0    
-----------         -------------
0 | 1 2 2 1         0 | 1 2 3 2 1
1 | 2 3 3 2         1 | 2 3 4 3 2
1 | 2 3 3 2         2 | 3 4 5 4 3
0 | 1 2 2 1         1 | 2 3 4 3 2
                    0 | 1 2 3 2 1
```

You could also combine this in a single list comprehension:

```
M = [[n-(abs(r)+abs(c))//2 for c in range(1-n,n,2)] for r in range(1-n,n,2)]
```

or in a more basic for-loop:

```
for r in range(1-n,n,2):                    # r\c | -3 -1  1  3
    for c in range(1-n,n,2):                # -3  |  1  2  2  1
        print(n-(abs(r)+abs(c))//2,end=" ") # -1  |  2  3  3  2
    print()                                 #  1  |  2  3  3  2
                                            #  3  |  1  2  2  1
```